# My phone crashes while charging

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, charging, crashes, shutdown

My phone sometimes shuts down without a reason or warning. It often happens while it's charging. I'm not positive charging is an absolute requirement for this to happen, but I only remember it happening in that situation.

Then I go to it and find it not responding, just showing a battery filling up or filled up: it's charging while turned off. But I didn't turn it off, and it was still turned on when I plugged it in.

Sometimes, I can leave my phone like that a whole afternoon, noticing only after 3-4 hours that something is wrong. At that point, my phone has been turned off for an unknown amount of time, and who knows who could have tried to call me.

What is causing this? Is there a way to prevent it? Or to automatically turn the phone back on when it crashes like that?

My phone:

- Samsung Galaxy Q (SGH-T589W)
- Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread
- Processor: 600MHz Qualcomm MSM7227 (if indeed it's the same as the Gravity Smart, because information on the Galaxy Q is rare)
- Internal storage: 152 MB, some of which I think is taken up by the OS or useless stock software, because I can't ever seem to free it
- RAM: 279 MB
- SD card: 2 GB
- Carrier: Videotron